# about adding appleID in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

Found that when I add apple ID in xcode unavailable in my account, I was suspected xcode a problem, but when they add a friend's account no problem. I do not know if anyone else has encountered this kind of problem, hope can provide a solution, thank you every much! pic 1 is that adding my appleID。 pic 2 is that adding my friend's appleID

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

check that your certificate is not expired or not revoke. if it is so then go to to developer portal and create new certificate and check that your apple id is not expired.

Update :

Try to use xcode 7.1 or 7.2 if you are using beta version.

hope this will help :)

Comment: After xcode7.0 may not need to add apple ID certificate is not it?

Comment: Yes, but when I add the account will be given at a friend's xcode, he's not a test version. So I think it does not matter and xcode version.

Comment: Then also try once on xcode 7.1 or 7.2 not on beta version if you have available or installed. and second thing make sure for your credentials that you are not entering wrong apple id or password.

Comment: Okay, I'll look for a 7.1 or 7.2 version of Xcode login test. Anyway thank you very much

Comment: This is a bug you? My apple ID on a colleague's Xcode can sign, not another, they are version 7.2, my test version of Xcode can log colleague AppleID, but I can not log in. WTF?

Comment: hehe... sometimes happens like this. your apple id is new? means have you used it before to signin in xcode?

Comment: No, just recently I switched to a new company, the use of time in the new company mac, log in to your AppleID found the bug, but I have not encountered before, but did not in the Google search to similar problems. So I hope to find the answers here.

Comment: It is happen sometime when you are trying to login in xcode beta version with new apple id.

Comment: no, maybe I did not express clearly, I mean, I've been using this appleID, not a new appleID (ps. I'm Chinese, my English is poor, so I had the help of Google translate and communicate with you)

Comment: I think you should use xcode 7.2 instead of that beta version